# Higher theory o $C^{\ast}$-algebras and the $C^{\ast}$-algebra of a $\infty$-groupoid

Tags: ct.category-theory, operator-theory, higher-category-theory, c-star-algebras, infinity-categories

Has someone already worked out what would be the infinity categorical analogue of the category of $C^{\ast}$-algebras? Given a groupoid $G$ we can associate a $C^{\ast}$-algebra $C^* (G)$, can we do something similar with a $\infty$-groupoid?

Comment: I  wonder if there would be an example of a  $C^*$ algebra obtained in this way you mentioned whose  all elements are zero divisor?Please see this question as a possible related post https://www.physicsoverflow.org/45602/the-category-algebras-equivalent-the-category-of-algebras

Comment: Possibly related: [C*-algebraic drawings of dendroidal sets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.05799)

Comment: You are well come! Thank you toofor your very interesting answer